# Stop thread and again start giving IllegalThreadStateException in blackberry

Tags: java, multithreading, blackberry, java-me

I am getting `IllegalThreadStateException` exception when using following code:
I have already started this thread once(by using `thread.start()`) and again trying to start it at another place, so used following code:

```
thread.interrupt();
thread.start();
```

But `thread.start()` is throwing `IllegalThreadStateException`.

What should I use to solve it?

Comment: just added `java` tag, since it is common to any `java`.

Comment: @VitKhudenko actually it already has java-me. But yeah it still needs java tag

Answer (score 21):

`Thread` objects are only meant to be started once.  If you need to stop/interrupt a `Thread`, and then want to start it again, you should create a new instance, and call `start()` on it:

```java
thread.interrupt();  // if you need to make sure thread's run() method stops ASAP
thread = new MyThreadSubclass();
thread.start();
```

[From the API docs](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29)

> **IllegalThreadStateException** - if the thread was already started.

I know it's not 100% clear that you can't call `start()` again, even if you previously called `interrupt()`, but that's the way it works.

If you look at the [API docs for standard Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29), this issue is more clear.

Comment: Thanks Nate. But when I was trying to use 'thread.interrupt();'
It is again showing exception as - **IllegalThreadStateException**.

Comment: @AnkitRox, the API docs don't show that `interrupt()` throws any exceptions.  However, my guess would be that you're calling `interrupt()` even before the 1st time that you run this code.  You really would only need to interrupt the thread if it's been started once.  So, the 2nd, 3rd, etc. times you want to call `start()`, you might call `interrupt()` right beforehand.  You could test `thread.isAlive()` before calling `thread.interrupt()`.  If that doesn't work, you need to show some more code (e.g. how you create the Thread object).

Comment: I have a class as `AsyncUploadQuestionsAndLeads` which is extended by `Thread`. 

Initializing Thread object by using:

`AsyncUploadQuestionsAndLeads uploadThread = new AsyncUploadQuestionsAndLeads(event);`


And starting the thread from some other place:
`uploadThread.start();`

After some time, I am using the code as:
`uploadThread.interrupt();
uploadThread.start();`

This is my code procedure which I have followed.

One more Question is - Does thread stops itself, when it completes it's run block?

Comment: Please read my answer.  You can't call `interrupt()`, and then call `start()` right after that, *on the same instance*.  If you are going to call `start()` a second time, you have to create a new instance with `uploadThread = new AsyncUploadQuestionsAndLeads(event)` again.  And, yes, the thread essentially stops when the `run()` method completes.  After `run()` completes, you cannot call `start()` again on the same instance.  You must create a **new** one.

Comment: Thanks Nate. I was also trying your method.
But the problem occurred at that time was, it was start a new thread for the new instance and previous thread was also working.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to Nate's answer.

AnkitRox states in his comment:

> Thanks Nate. I was also trying your method. But the problem occurred at that time was, it was start a new thread for the new instance and previous thread was also working.

So it looks like the problem is *"the thread is still running even if I called interrupt on it"*. Consider this sample (it is ugly, but enough to show the main idea):

```
final Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++); // simulate some action
            System.out.println("hi, interrupted = " 
                    + Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
        }
    }
});
t.start();
new Timer(true).schedule(
    new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            t.interrupt();
        }
    },
    1000 // 1 second delay
);
```

Note, the thread continues to run even after `interrupt()` has been called. The produced output is:

```
hi, interrupted = false
hi, interrupted = true
hi, interrupted = true
hi, interrupted = true
...
hi, interrupted = true
```

Actually the programm never stops unless closed forcefully. So what then the `interrupt()` does? It just sets the **interrupted flag** to `true`. After `interrupt()` has been called the `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` starts to return `false`. And that's all.

Another case is if `interrupt()` is called while the thread is blocked in an invocation of one of the methods that throw `InterruptedException`, then that method will return throwing the `InterruptedException`. And if thread's code just "eats" that exception, then the thread will still continue running, consider a sample:

```
final Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("hi, interrupted = " 
                    + Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("got InterruptedException");
            }
        }
    }
});
t.start();
new Timer(true).schedule(
    new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            t.interrupt();
        }
    },
    1000 // 1 second delay
);
```

Note, the thread continues to run even after `interrupt()` has been called. The produced output is:

```
hi, interrupted = false
got InterruptedException
hi, interrupted = false
hi, interrupted = false
...
hi, interrupted = false
```

Note, this time `interrupted = false` even after `interrupt()` has been called. This is because whenever `InterruptedException` is caught, the **interrupted flag** is reset to `false`.

In Java stopping a thread is **cooperative** mechanism. Meaning it can not be done without cooperation from the thread itself. Here is the fixed version of the above sample:

```
final Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            System.out.println("hi, interrupted = " 
                    + Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("we've been interrupted");
                // restore the interrupted flag
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
});
t.start();
new Timer(true).schedule(
    new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            t.interrupt();
        }
    },
    1000 // 1 second delay
);
```

So the correct approach should be to periodically check the **interrupted flag**. And if interrupted status is detected then just return ASAP. Another common option is not to use `Thread.interrupt()` at all, but [some custom boolean instead](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Threads/Thesafewaytostopathread.htm).

Comment: great explanation.  not ugly at all :)