# Remove Please wait popup screen on back key

Tags: blackberry

I am using below code for creating please wait popup in Blackberry application.I want to remove that popup screen on **back press** of device but i am not able to do this because 
at the time of showing please wait popup the whole screen is blocked till completion of thread operation.

Here is my code:

```java
public class PleaseWaitLoginPopupScreen extends PopupScreen {

    //statics ------------------------------------------------------------------

    private AnimatedGIFField _ourAnimation = null;
    private LabelField _ourLabelField = null;
    private static String pleaseWaitText="";
    private static PleaseWaitLoginPopupScreen ref;

    public static PleaseWaitLoginPopupScreen getInstance(){
        if(ref!=null){
            ref=new PleaseWaitLoginPopupScreen(Constant.PLEASE_WAIT_TEXT);
        }
        return ref;
    }

    public PleaseWaitLoginPopupScreen(String text) {
        super(new VerticalFieldManager(VerticalFieldManager.VERTICAL_SCROLL | VerticalFieldManager.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR));
        GIFEncodedImage ourAnimation = (GIFEncodedImage) GIFEncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("loader.gif");
        _ourAnimation = new AnimatedGIFField(ourAnimation, Field.FIELD_HCENTER);
        this.add(_ourAnimation);
        _ourLabelField = new LabelField(text, Field.FIELD_HCENTER);
        this.add(_ourLabelField);
    }

    public static void showScreenAndWait(final Runnable runThis, String text) {
        pleaseWaitText=text;
        final PleaseWaitLoginPopupScreen thisScreen = new PleaseWaitLoginPopupScreen(text);
        Thread threadToRun = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                // First, display this screen
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(thisScreen);
                    }
                });
                boolean exceptionFlag = false;
                // Now run the code that must be executed in the Background
                try {
                    runThis.run();
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    exceptionFlag = true;
                    t.printStackTrace();
                    //throw new RuntimeException("Exception detected while waiting: " + t.toString());

                }finally{
                    // Now dismiss this screen
                    if(exceptionFlag){//IF EXCEPTION OCURES THAN THIS CODE WILL RUN TO STOP THE PLEASE WAIT POP TASK
                        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(thisScreen);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        threadToRun.start();
    }

    public void dismissPopupScreen(){
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(PleaseWaitLoginPopupScreen.this);
            }
        });
        /*synchronized (UiApplication.getEventLock()) {
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(PleaseWaitLoginPopupScreen.this);
        }*/
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `AnimatedGIFField` here in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to catch the **Back** (ESC) key press, and use that to close the popup screen, then you can override the [keyChar(char,int,int)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Screen.html#keyChar%28char,int,int%29) method in your `PleaseWaitLoginPopupScreen` class:

```java
   protected boolean keyChar(char c, int status, int time) {
      if (c == Characters.ESCAPE) {
         close();
      }
      return super.keyChar(c, status, time);
   }
```

However, all this will do is simply remove the popup screen.  You probably should also try to stop the `Runnable` that you started.  In BlackBerry Java, this needs to be done collaboratively between the code requesting the stop, and the `Runnable` itself.

[See this answer by Arhimed for more on this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13552114/119114)

In your case, you could store the `Thread` variable as a member

```java
private Thread _threadToRun;
```

assign it in `showScreenAndWait()`:

```java
thisScreen._threadToRun = new Thread() {
```

and then cancel it in the `keyChar()` method I showed with this:

```java
   protected boolean keyChar(char c, int status, int time) {
      if (c == Characters.ESCAPE) {
         _threadToRun.interrupt();
         close();
      }
      return super.keyChar(c, status, time);
   }
```

Then, in the `Runnable()` that you pass to `showScreenAndWait()`, you will need to put in a few checks to see if the thread has been interrupted:

```java
 if (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
     // do more stuff
 }
```

How you place those checks depends on the task.   If you're downloading 10 files in your `run()` method, you probably should put an `isInterrupted()` check in between each of the 10 downloads.  If `run()` contains a `while()` loop, check once per loop.  That will determine **when** the job can be stopped.