# When I run Thread second time: java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have Thrad and Handler:

```
Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        //do somethink
    }
};

Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //do somethink
        msg.obj = 1;
        handler.sendMessage(msg);
        thread.interrupt();
    }
});
```

When app start, at first time **thread.start();** all work fine.
But when I try start **thread.start();** second time from button I have:

> E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started.

Comment: also an ans here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13538668/stop-thread-and-again-start-giving-illegalthreadstateexception-in-blackberry

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You should check state of that thread before starting it.

```
if (thread.getState() == Thread.State.NEW)
{
     thread.start();
}
```

Comment: it fixes the crash, but the panel is dead...

Answer (score 4):

Its not a good Idea to start a Thread more then once.
You have to check Whether a Thread is already started or not. if Thread not started yet

```
if(!thread.isAlive()){
thread.start();
}
```

The Better Idea is to **Create new Thread** instance.

Comment: i think there should be ! in `if(!thread.isAlive())...` but finished thread is not in state `NEW` and not alive at same time, so the exception can still occure

Comment: thread.isAlive() is prone to "IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started" - better use thread.getState().

Comment: Tried it, still not working.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of run(), your thread dies.  If you want to keep it alive, then add a blocking queue to the thread and make run() a big while loop that reads from the queue.  Instead of calling start for each message, just add it to the queue instead.

Of course, you still have to call start() once (when your program initializes).